# This improper integral doesn't converge, does it?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, improper-integrals

(disclaimer: I don't know if it's legit to share a picture of my calculations, and not rewriting it in LATEX notation - let me know if this is legit or not)

my question is that: are my calculations correct?

I have to solve this exercise: it's an improper integral.
before using integration by parts, I've studied the bounds, in order to check where the function is undefined. And I got that when solving the function for $x = 3$ the denominator is 0, therefore the function is undefined (i.e division by zero).
Therefore, I've taken the limit as x approaches 3. And then I've solved the integral with $x$ as the upper bound.

As stated above, I've used integration by parts by choosing $$ u = x $$ (because the derivative of the polynomial, hopefully, is going to become some smaller value) And $$ dv = (1 / (3 - x)) $$ because the antiderivative is simply equal to log (natural log, i.e with base $e$) (of course the argument of log must be the absolute value)

Now, by integrating by parts and after having evaluated the limit of the antiderivative, I got that the limit doesn't exist, because the limit of the function evaluated in the upper bound is undefined (i.e the natural log is undefined for x = 3). Is it true? And if it's true, the integral doesn't converge, right?
[image: this is my attempt to solve it]

Comment: You should write out your working using LaTeX...Don't include images of handwritten work especially since it is hard for people to read, it would be somewhat better if you put an image of your working written in LaTeX.

Comment: By a linear change of variable, $$\int_0^2\left(\frac3u-1\right)du=3\int_0^2\frac{du}u-2$$ leaves little doubt.

Comment: Be careful about using $x$ in your limits of integration and the variable that you're integrating against.  This is confusing because we don't know which $x$ is which.

Comment: @MichaelBurr you're right, I should've written $t$ inside the integral. during exam I'll write this way, but this is just an exercise to learn how to put theory into practice

Comment: A clever form of $0$ makes it a little clearer in my opinion. Writing $\frac{x}{x-3}$ as $\frac{x-3+3}{x-3} = 1 + \frac{3}{x-3}$, you can see that it'll diverge immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the integral does not converge, but you made some mistakes and overcomplicated the solution in general.

*The mistake*: If $v=\log(3-x)$, then $v'=-\frac{1}{3-x}$. You missed a minus sign.

*The overcomplication*:

Instead of using per partes, you can rewrite

$$\frac{x}{3-x} = \frac{x-3+3}{3-x} = \frac{-(3-x)}{3-x} + \frac{3}{3-x} = \frac{3}{3-x} - 1$$

and only integrate after this rearrangement. No need for per partes, a simple introduction of a new variable $u=3-x$ is sufficient and you get (since $du = -dx$):

$$\int_1^3\frac{x}{3-x}dx = 3\int_1^3 \frac{1}{3-x}dx - \int_1^3 1dx = 3\int_2^0-\frac{1}{u}du - 2 = 3\int_0^2\frac1udu - 2$$

now you can either remember that the integral of $\frac{1}{u}$ diverges around $0$, or you can write it out, since

$$\int_0^2\frac1udu=\lim_{x\to 0}\int_x^2\frac1udu = \lim_{x\to 0} (\ln(2)-\ln(x))$$ and the limit above does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Since the objective is to decide on the convergence of the integral, you can make it a little simpler. In fact, since $g(x)=x$ is continuous on $[1,3]$ and $g(3)\ne 0$, the convergence of the original integral is equivalent to the convergence of $\int_1^3 \frac{1}{x-3}\,dx$. This last integral is divergent:
$$
\int_1^3 \frac{1}{x-3}dx = \lim_{b\to 3}\int_1^b\frac{1}{x-3} dx = \lim_{b\to 3}\left[\log|x-3|\right]_1^b = \infty.
$$